# different ways to calculate satellite height

Tags: orbital-elements, altitude, calculation

I found 2 formulas for calculating height. First is:

```
height = magnitude(satillate_position_vector) - Earth_radius
```

Second is:

```
height = Semimajor_axis * (1 - eccentricity) - Earth_radius
```

Which of them is correct for calculation? And if them both correct then which of these formulas is used for. Because results are different even if I use `satillate_position_vector` for calculating orbital elements like `Semimajor_axis`  and `eccentricity`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first formula gives you the altitude at a particular point in the orbit, assuming that the position vector is the satellite's current position relative to the center of the Earth.

The second formula is the altitude of the [periapsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apsis) (lowest point) of an elliptical orbit.